# Render an entity in a string and return it through an AJAX callback in a custom form

Tags: theming, 8, forms, entities, ajax

I use the code snippet from:
[render a drupal 8 entity in a string](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179520/render-a-drupal-8-entity-in-a-string)

```
$node = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nodeid);
$view_builder = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
$renderarray = $view_builder->view($node, 'full');
$html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($renderarray);
```

It works in a normal controller class without problems. But I did not get it to work in an Ajax Callback in a Custom Form.

The $html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);  returns nothing.

Where ist the problem? Here is the reduced code of my test form:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;


class SearchApiPageBlockForm extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'search_api_page_block_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $args = array()) {

    $form['form']['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions',);
    $form['form']['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('TESTBUTTON!'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => '::myAjaxCallback',
      ),
    );

    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }


  public function myAjaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('comment');
    $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('comment');
    $node = $storage->load(103); //cid 103 already exists
    $build = $view_builder->view($node);

    dpm('before rendering'); // -> dpm output is: 'before rendering' 

    $html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);  

    dpm($html);// -> dpm has no output 
    dpm('after rendering');// -> dpm has no output

    }

}
```

My goal is, to return the html of an entity via the

```
$response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#testtmp_message', $output));
```

UPDATE: Content of build:
dpm(build)

[image]

Comment: The code seems to work, on a first quick look. Are you getting any errors (webserver longs or Drupal logger entries) ?

Comment: Normally you don't need to render, did you try to use the build array for the ajax command? `$response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#testtmp_message', $build));`

Comment: @Stefanos Petrakis I have enabled Home > Administration > Configuration > Development  "All messages, with backtrace information" and added error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE); 
in my settings.php but there were no errors reported.

Comment: @4k4 I tried to return the $build directly but nothing changes: $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#testtmp_message', $build));
I tried a normal return array with success: $build = ['#type' => 'html_tag', '#tag' => 'p', '#value' => 'HERE',];

Comment: @userpixel, what is in $build? - btw. for reporting errors, often you don't see the error on screen when it is an ajax reponse, check the content of the response in the browser debugging tools.

Comment: @4k4 Standard array ('HERE') gives no browser console error but return $build gives 2 errors: http://drupal8-2.dd:8083/node/35?ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax 500 (Internal Server Error) and 
Uncaught D…l.AjaxError {message: "↵An AJAX HTTP error occurred.↵HTTP Result Code: 50…tatusText: Internal Server Error↵ResponseText: {}", name: "AjaxError"}

Comment: @4k4 I updated my post with content of $build.

Comment: 500 is still production settings,  no error reporting. Do you have errors in /admin/reports/dblog?

Comment: @4k4 Yes there is a log message for this ajax call: Message: Drupal\Core\Form\FormAjaxException: in Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm() (line 333 of /Users/user/Sites/devdesktop/drupal8-2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php) Location: http://drupal8-2.dd:8083/node/35?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax&ajax_form=1

Comment: The AjaxException is normally catched by FormAjaxSubscriber to generate the ajax response. Don't see anything in the code where the formbuilder is called, maybe there is a form in the comment which causes the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in my question is OK. The problem was caused by a conflict by calling the form from `hook_preprocess_field()`. I changed the hook, and I am calling the form from `template_preprocess_block()` and the AJAX callback of the entity gets fine.

4k4 put me on the right track. Thank you.